# Dedicated board | place for Microsoft exam discussion

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, testing

I know that according to the NDA which you accept before taking the exam it is prohibited to discuss, reveal, share etc but the question is very hot - let's suppose I've faced a bunch of questions which are ...ambiguous or strange or do not have the correct answer IMO and I want to discuss it (in fact ask a question(s) and discuss possible answers using hivemind).

Posting each question as a separate thread on different board (e.g. SO\SU\ShP\DBA etc) is a bad idea (as for me) that's why this question has risen.

To not mess with the NDA and Microsoft rights, let's say I can "wrap an exam question in a "veiled form" of a SO-type question" for example.

Maybe the other (better?) way exists of course.

The main idea is that there is no "dedicated" site to discuss exam questions all around the Internet - and of course, I wouldn't say that dumps-selling sites are the perfect place to discuss the Q&A.

Anyway, I'll be very appreciated for pointing me in the right direction - I really hope that this idea has visited not only me and not only today:)

PS Do not offer the born-to-learn community, please.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that according to the NDA which you accept before taking the exam it is prohibited to discuss, reveal, share etc

Let's not create a place for users to breach that NDA then.

> The main idea is that there is no "dedicated" site to discuss exam questions all around the Internet

And the SE network is a site of Q/A sites, not a traditional forum and not suited for discussions.

> Anyway, I'll be very appreciated for pointing me in the right direction

I doubt within the SE network there will be a place for such site. Both based on its format and the fact that the content would go stale quickly.

If all other options like Quora/reddit fail, host your own server with a BBS service on it.

Comment: Sure I'm not suggesting the NDA breaking, I've clearly stated it in my initial post. And I disagree that SE is a just "Q&A" site - in fact, the discussions in answer comments are a part of a Q&A flow so the discussion has to be alas. However, I agree that the format is not well-suited for SE network but would disagree about questions being stale - that's relevant to all questions on SE network sites too - they can (and will) be stale during the time, so the exam questions discussion is the same situation. But I think in general you're right and SE boards aren't a good choice for it. Thanks

Comment: @Sergey actually, comments are not for discussion but for asking clarifications. Here, comments are treated as a 2nd-class citizen and can be removed anytime. *Ideally*, posts shouldn't have any comments left after the OP has already handled all the issues/requests in their posts.